# CP-violating coupling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, parity, charge-conjugation

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3842.pdf), after equation (38), there is the statement that the term
$$\bar{t}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu\gamma_5tZ_\mu$$
is CP-violating.

How exactly do we see this? Can anyone make explicit how we derive the transformation of this term under CP?